# postMessage not working for cross domain production urls

Tags: javascript, console, cross-domain, postmessage

I'm trying to figure out a way for two tabs with different domains be able to communicate with each other (back and forth of messages).

The two websites are as follows:

1. https://twitter.com/home (sender)
2. https://chat.openai.com/ (receiver)

For this case lets assume twitter's tab is the sender and chat gpt tab is the receiver tab.

Below is the code that I run the twitte's console.

```
// twitter's console
childWindow = window.open('https://chat.openai.com/');
```

once I run the above code it spawns a new tab and then I paste the below code in twitter's tab to register an event listener

```
// chat gpt's console
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => console.log(event));
```

Now to send a message from the twitter's tab to chat gpt tab

```
// twitter's console
childWin.postMessage('hello message from twitter', 'https://chat.openai.com/');
```

On investigation I can see two problems,

1. For some reason, `childWindow.window` value becomes null after 1-2 sec in twitter's console.
2. Even if #1 doesn't happen, when we call the postMessage sometimes it sends the event but the data doesn't have the exact message but rather has some error like (could copy that).

Any idea, how can we solve this problem.

Comment: Those domains are clearly third party, which you have no access to. Therefore CORS will not work, and `postMessage()` support will not have been enabled on them. What you are trying to do will not be possible on the client side.